# how to move these vertices out evenly

Tags: modeling

ok, I don't know how to ask this question properly which is why I couldn't find a solution on google.

basically, I want just the middle vertices to pop out evenly that way I could give it a half circle depth. I included a picture to help make sense of what I'm trying to ask.[image]
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried with alt+S ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you need is '*shrink/fatten*' which shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> :

[image]

Once done, you can tune it with the operator panel on the left, and check the '*offset even*' option which gives a more even... offset...